# pandas apply for performance

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have a pandas apply function that runs inference over a 10k csv of strings

```
account messages
0   th_account  Forgot to tell you Evan went to sleep a little...
1   th_account  Hey I heard your buying a house I m getting ri...
2   th_account  They re releasing a 16 MacBook
3   th_account  5 cups of coffee today I may break the record
4   th_account  Apple Store Items in order W544414717 were del...
```

The function takes about 17 seconds to run. 
I'm working on a text classifier and was wondering if there is a quicker way to write it

```
def _predict(messages):
    results = []
    for message in messages:
        message = vectorizer.transform([message])
        message = message.toarray()
        results.append(model.predict(message))
    return results

df["pred"] = _predict(df.messages.values)
```

the `vectorizer` is a `TfidfVectorizer` and  `model` is a GaussianNB model from sklearn.
I need to loop through every messsage in the csv and perform a prediction to be shown in a new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try built-in function `apply` in `pandas`. Its underlying uses C language passby GIL. But still slow.

```py
def _predict(message):
    """message is each row in dataframe

    Each row of dataframe return a result
    """
    message = vectorizer.transform([message])
    message = message.toarray()
    return model.predict(message)

df["pred"] = df.apply(_predict, axis=1)
```

You can run the following code to evaluate the time.

```py
df.head().apply(_predict, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but using apply was the first thing i tried. Its about the same amount of time